# Как поменять кавычку внутри слова, не меняя другие кавычки в тексте

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Нужно сделать регулярными выражениями. Как написать шаблон для замены кавычек c " на ' - только тех которые находятся внутри слов?

```
var text = 'Эту "задачу" "нужн"о сделать" регулярным"и выраже"ниями';
var pattern = '/???/';
var result = text.replace(pattern, "'");
console.log(result);
```

Comment: текст на русском или любой язык может быть?

Comment: проще наверно только на русском

Answer (score 2):

Решение, которое будет работать во всех браузерах, не должно содержать блока предварительного просмотра назад. Кроме того, чтобы заменить кавычки, которые следуют друг за другом через одну букву, без блока предварительного просмотра *вперёд* не обойтись.

Поэтому лучшее решение будет

```js
var text = 'Эту "задачу" "ну"ж"н"о сделать" регулярным"и выраже"ниями';
var pattern = /([а-яё])"(?=[а-яё])/ig;
var result = text.replace(pattern, "$1'");
console.log(result);
```

См. [**демо регулярного выражения**](https://regex101.com/r/pN2UzI/1).

**Подробности**

- `([а-яё])` - Захватывающая группа №1 (ссылка на значение этой группы из шаблона замены осуществляется с помощью `$1`): буква русского алфавита
- `"` - двойная кавычка
- `(?=[а-яё])` - блок предварительного просмотра вперёд, который проверяет следующее условие: сразу после знака `"` должна стоять буква русского алфавита
- `ig`  - модификаторы

  - `i` - регистронезависимость включена
  - `g` - поиск всех вхождений включен

Для браузеров и сред, поддерживающих стандарт ECMAScript 2018, можно использовать следующее решение для любого языка:

```js
var pattern = /(?<=\p{L})"(?=\p{L})/gu;
var result = 'Эту "задачу" "ну"ж"н"о сделать" регулярным"и выраже"ниями'.replace(pattern, "'");
console.log(result);
```

`\p{L}` находит любую букву.

Answer (score 1):

Так как кавычка *внутри* слова, слева и справа от нее должны быть буквы.

Поэтому для русского языка регулярка может иметь вид `/([а-яё])"([а-яё])/g`.

Шаблон замены: "$1'$2" → взять первую и вторую группы (буквы между которыми была кавычка) и поставить между ними одинарную кавычку:

```js
var text = 'Эту "задачу" "нужн"о сделать" регулярным"и выраже"ниями';
var pattern = /([а-яё])"([а-яё])/g;
var result = text.replace(pattern, "$1'$2");
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var text = 'Эту "задачу" "нужн"о сделать" регулярным"и выраже"ниями';
var result = text.replace(/(?<=\S)\"(?=\S)/g, "\'");

console.log(result);
```

Comment: что-то ошибку код выдает

Comment: @ValeriyPetukhov, какую ошибку? Проверьте здесь, нажав на `Выполнить код`

Comment: Здесь выдает
{
  "message": "SyntaxError: invalid regexp group",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 14,
  "colno": 26
}

Comment: @ValeriyPetukhov, вы в каком браузере находитесь?

Comment: браузер firefox

Comment: @ValeriyPetukhov, проверьте в другом браузере, к примеру в хроме, все прекрасно работает, код правильный.

Comment: Да сорри, в хроме все заработало